# Typescript error - No overload matches this call for firerbase updatePassword method

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my angular component code -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { reauthenticateWithCredential } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { EmailAuthProvider } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getAuth, updatePassword } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { FirebaseError } from '@firebase/util';

export class CustomValidators {
  static MatchValidator(source: string, target: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const sourceCtrl = control.get(source);
      const targetCtrl = control.get(target);

      return sourceCtrl && targetCtrl && sourceCtrl.value !== targetCtrl.value
        ? { mismatch: true }
        : null;
    };
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-password',
  templateUrl: './update-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-password.component.css']
})
export class UpdatePasswordComponent {
  constructor() { }

  passwordCharLen: number = 6
  formErrStatus: boolean = false;
  errorMessage: string = ""

  updatePassword = new FormGroup(
    {
      currentPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.passwordCharLen)]),
      newPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.passwordCharLen)]),
      confirmNewPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.passwordCharLen)]),
    },
    [CustomValidators.MatchValidator('newPassword', 'confirmNewPassword')]
  );

  async updateAccountPassword(): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('updatePassword:', this.updatePassword.value)

    if (!this.updatePassword.valid) {
      console.log('Form validation failed')
      console.log('form data: ', this.updatePassword)
      this.formErrStatus = true;
      this.errorMessage = "Please enter all above details.";
      return false
    } else {
      this.formErrStatus = false;
      this.errorMessage = "";
    }

    if (this.updatePassword.value.currentPassword == this.updatePassword.value.newPassword) {
      this.formErrStatus = true;
      this.errorMessage = "New Password should be same as current password";
      return false
    }

    const auth = getAuth()
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
      auth.currentUser?.email!,
      this.updatePassword.value.currentPassword!
    )
    const newPassword = this.updatePassword.value.newPassword

    if (user) {
      try {
        await reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential)
      } catch (error: unknown) {
        console.log('Got error in reauthenticate user:', error)

        if (error instanceof FirebaseError) {
          console.log('error code:', error.code)
          console.log('error message:', error.message)

          if (error.code == 'auth/wrong-password') {
            this.formErrStatus = true;
            this.errorMessage = "Invalid current password";
            return false
          }
        }
      }

      console.log('user reauthenticate successfully.')

      try {
        await updatePassword(user, newPassword)
      } catch (error: unknown) {
        console.log('Error in updatePassword: ', error)
      }

    }

    return true
  }

  get passwordMatchError() {
    return (
      this.updatePassword.getError('mismatch') &&
      this.updatePassword.get('confirmNewPassword')?.touched
    );
  }
}
```

At the following piece of code -

```
try {
    await updatePassword(user, newPassword)
} catch (error: unknown) {
    console.log('Error in updatePassword: ', error)
}
```

I'm getting this typescript error.

[image]

Typescript error -

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(user: User, newPassword: string): Promise<void>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'import("/Users/sureshkumarmajhi/Documents/Projects/AngularJS/project-manager/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-public").User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/sureshkumarmajhi/Documents/Projects/AngularJS/project-manager/node_modules/@firebase/auth-types/index").User'.
      Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'User': linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential, linkWithCredential, linkWithPhoneNumber, linkWithPopup, and 14 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(user: User, newPassword: string): Promise<void>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
```

I know this is coming because the typescript is not getting the right user type. But I've exactly followed the same process the way it has been mentioned in the firebase doc.

Firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Need some help.